# .net3.5 System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed Twice

Tags: c#, .net, timer, windows-services

I am coding for a windows service project, i use a System.Timers.Timer for some work.

I set the interval 2000 milliseconds.

But i found that the timer will raise the Elapsed event 1 time in the first 2000 milliseconds and then raise the Elasped event twice for every other 2000 milliseconds.

I think there is something wrong with my program, i try to solve it by lock:

```
var timer_lock = new object();
DateTime last_elapse_time = DateTime.MinValue;
var _tm = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
_tm.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
{
    lock (timer_lock)
    {
        var cur_time = DateTime.Now;
        var interval = (cur_time - last_elapse_time).TotalMilliseconds;
        if (interval < 2000)
            return;
        last_elapse_time = cur_time;
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(cur_time.Second);
    };
}
_tm.Start();
```

But i found it does not work, Trace.WriteLine runs twice, then i tried another test:

```
static void Main()
{
    new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() => {
        while (true)
        {
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((object context) =>
            {
                var cur_time = DateTime.Now;
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(cur_time.Second);
            });
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    })).Start();
}
```

But nothing changes..

I make a new console project to test the problem, then the problem disappears, the timer works well.

Then i make a new windows service project, then the problem occurs again.

I debug the windows service project by run `OnStart()` method in `Main()`, is this the reason?

Comment: The code looks broken with the timer being a local variable.  That means that you can never stop the timer so you can't implement OnStop() correctly.  Start more than once, which you do by also calling it from Main(), and you'll have multiple timers firing the Elapsed event.

Comment: i tried make the timer as a field of Service, but it turns to raise the Elapsed event 3 times..

Answer (score 0):

just set `var _tm = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);` Outside the onstart method... for example, in constuctor. This should fix your problem

Comment: I tried make '_tm' as a field of the Service, then set value in constructor, only run '_tm.Start()' in 'OnStart()', to my surprise, it turns to run three times when elapsed...

Comment: if(!_tm.isEnabled) _tm.Start();

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved by using lock and check interval.